# How can I send stuff commands to a start-in-detached screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Any session that I start with "-d -m" doesn't accept "-X stuff [...]" commands unless I've attached to the screen at least once.  There is no error message, the commands just do not get through.

The problem is that I start the session from a cron job and am unable to attach to the screen from within cron.

**Steps to repeat**

```
$ screen -m -d -S mydaemon bash
$ screen -S mydaemon -X stuff "`printf "exit\\r"`"
$ screen -ls
        32456.mydaemon  (Detached)
$ screen -r -S mydaemon
$ ^a d
$ screen -S mydaemon -X stuff "`printf "exit\\r"`"
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user
```

^a d indicates pressing Ctrl+a then pressing d.

**Versions**

```
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: The best answer to this question is [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870705). I leave my kludgey solution here, anyway, in case it inspires a solution to a similar problem.

---

A possible workaround is to use a second, already running and detached screen session to start the screen session to which you want to send the "stuff" command in attached mode, and then send that screen session a detach command and then the stuff command.

```
$ screen -dmS spawner
$ screen -S spawner -X screen screen -dR mydaemon
$ sleep 1 # may be necessary
$ screen -S mydaemon -X detach
$ screen -S mydaemon -X stuff "whatever"
```

(Note: the doubled "screen" is *not* a typo!) You are still left with an unstuffable screen session (spawner) but if the resources it takes are important you can always just use "kill -TERM ..." or its ilk to terminate it (or have it automatically exit after a certain amount of time by starting it with something like

```
$ screen -dmS spawner bash -c "sleep 60"
```

or similar).

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I forgot that I discovered that I had had to add a short sleep after creating the screen session and its detachment via -X, to prevent race conditions. The answer has been edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `tmux` instead? It is much more suitable for non-interactive tasks.

Comment: I don't currently have tmux installed but I can look into it.  Is there a guide or can you provide an example for what I need?

Comment: `man tmux` pretty much cover everything, but this should be pretty much identical to what you want: http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/07/02/tmux-%E2%80%93-the-terminal-multiplexer-part-2/#tmux-shell-scripting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Ron Kaminsky.

I found another way to kill 'spawner' screen

```
    $ screen -dmS spawner
    $ screen -S spawner -X screen screen -dR mydaemon
    $ sleep 1 # may be necessary
    $ screen -S mydaemon -X detach
```

and add below line

```
    $ screen -S mydaemon -X screen screen -S spawner -dR
    $ sleep 1 # may be necessary
    $ screen -S spawner -X detach
    $ screen -S spawner -X kill
```

Comment: Anyway, I can't add comment to other guy'answer. what happen to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

> screen -d -m /bin/bash "test.sh"

screen (detached) (mobile) (shell) "What to execute"

```
$ screen -d -m /bin/bash "test.sh"
$ screen -li
There is a screen on:
        8540..Satelite  (10/17/2013 04:53:22 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-matt.
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the .screenrc file, you can set things to start;

```
screen -t <title> <window position> <command>
```

So, if you wanted to start `top` in window `7`, you'd do

```
screen -t window7top 7 top
```

Comment: Your response is not applicable.