# Shell GNU-Screen -X Stuff problems

Tags: linux, bash, shell, printf, gnu-screen

```
OPTIONS="java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar"
PROCESS=server01

screen -dmS $PROCESS $OPTIONS nogui             # Starting the application
screen -x $PROCESS -X stuff `printf "stop\r"`   # Closing the application
screen -x $PROCESS                              # Attaching to the terminal of the application
```

The application works fine at the start, however I get problems with `stuff 'printf "stop/r"'`
It seems not to work when I just start up, wait some time and then try to stop it with the command above. But the strange thing is, that if I did `screen -x $PROCESS` and detach (`ctrl-A & ctrl-D`) and then I use the `Stop` command it does work. So is there a way around to `stuff printf` without `screen -x $PROCESS`?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the command string - i.e. `screen -x $PROCESS -X "stuff \`printf 'stop\r'\`"`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Makes it even not work, after doing first screen -x $PROCESS and then stopping it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding the argument **-p 0** should fix it. Something like this:

```
screen -x $PROCESS -p 0 -X stuff `printf "stop\r"`
```

(From screen documentation: -p window     Preselect the named window if it exists.)